# Convert distances to a polygon/map

Tags: polygon, distance

I'm trying to build a relative "map" of a room. Which will then be used to gather a relative position between those points using trilateration.

I was thinking one way would be to measure out the distances between a bunch of points in the room, and basically arrange them based on the intersections of radiuses into a polygon. I guess I'd get at least two different "flipped" version as well as orientation would to unspecified. But that would be a great start.

But how can I do this in the best way?

I was thinking I could work my way backwards so as an example to start from I've drawn up 4 points on paper:

```
A = (0,0)
B = (6,0)
C = (2,4)
D = (3,-3)
```

It looks sort of like a crooked kite. And these are the end points I'd like to come up with (relatively speaking).

And then I calculate the distances between those points:

```
A - B = d1 ( 6.00)
A - C = d2 (~4.47)
A - D = d3 (~4.24)
B - D = d4 (~4.24)
B - C = d5 (~5.66)
C - D = d6 (~7.07)
```

Great! Now comes the part I got stuck on. Reversing this somehow. Here's what I'm thinking now:

1. I place A somewhere
2. The position of B should be somewhere on the radial around A.
3. Then C should be in either of the two intersections of the two radials around A and B. This gives us two possible flipped (and arbitrarily oriented) versions of triangles between A - B - C. Let's call them P1 and P2.
4. Then adding D on the intersections of A, B and C should extend those triangles and still give us two possible polygons.
5. I manually choose between P1 or P2 and its orientation to get my relative map to match up with the real world.

I hope the process makes sense. And I would like it to work with N amounts of points (with at least 4 I guess?).

But trying to google for something similar has given me nothing, mostly because I don't know what it may be called. There must be a formula or theorem for this problem that I don't know of.

I guess the question is two-fold: Is there a better way to do this? Where can I read more about the actual formula/math behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I feel like there is a way for wolfram alpha to do this for me.

Comment: I'm thinking a little diagram might help...